# Javascript creation of objects

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I'm creating a javascript object that will store information about the user logged into my site (for easy access), but for me, It's been very difficult to understand the ways of creating an object in javascript. I've seen examples using the prototype way, and anothers using the closures way, I decided to stay with the closures, because I'll need only a single instance of this object, and so, don't is a big overhead.

I wonder if what I'm doing is correct, and if there is any way to improve my code, this is my code:

```
(function(window){
    var mysite = (function() {
        var me = this;

        return { //public interface
            init : function(userInfo){
                me.user = userInfo;
                return this;
            },
            sayHello : function(){
                return 'Hello, my name is ' + me.user.name + ' and I am ' + me.user.age + ' years old.';
            }
        }
    }());

    window.mysite = function(userInfo){
        return mysite.init(userInfo);
    }
})(window);

var mysite = mysite({name : 'Jonathan', age : 17});
mysite.sayHello();
```

**Edit #1**

If I would like to add sub-objects to the main object MySite, and these sub-objects have their own methods and properties, as well as access to properties and methods of the main object (MySite), I'd like to do something like this:

```
mysite.timezone.calculeUserTimezone();
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the prototype**

```
(function(window) {
    var MySite = function(opt) {
        this.user = opt;
    };

    MySite.prototype.sayHello = function() {
        return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.user.name + ' and I am ' + this.user.age + ' years old.';
    };

    window.mysite = function(options) {
        return new MySite(options);
    }
})(window);

var a = mysite({
    name: 'Jonathan',
    age: 17
});
console.log(a.sayHello());
```

I would go for the prototypical approach instead. Your not taking advantage of closures so this way is neater.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tqtkq/4/)

**Using closures**

```
(function(window) {
    var MySite = function(opt) {
        var user = opt;

        this.sayHello = function() {
            return 'Hello, my name is ' + user.name + ' and I am ' + user.age + ' years old.';
        }
    };

    window.mysite = function(options) {
        return new MySite(options);
    }
})(window);

var a = mysite({
    name: 'Jonathan',
    age: 17
});
console.log(a.sayHello());
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tqtkq/5/)

Comment: _Your not taking advantage of closures_ Could you explain this better? Following the example you posted, if I wanted the user to be private property, how would I do? Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan there is no such thing as private in JavaScript ;) I also forgot to mention that your code was a single object that keeps being re-initialized and doesn't allow you to create multiple instances.

Comment: But in my example `me.user` can't be acessed outside the closure.

Comment: @Jonathan and why does that matter?

Comment: Because I wouldn't want that a user with firebug has easy access to this property, I know that javascript is in practice, totally public, but I want to hinder access to this property. Now one last question, following the two examples you gave, if I had another object (inside mySite), with its own functions and properties, how could I do?

Comment: @Jonathan that's a stupid reason, no offence. That data can easily be extracted. the client-side is public. Security through obscurity is stupid. _do not make it difficult to develop your code for mediocre fake security reasons_. As for another object, that depends, should be easy.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the quote :). Regarding the last question, see my edit.

Comment: @Jonathan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1579/discussion-between-raynos-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var mysite = (function() {
        var me = this;

        return { //public interface
            init : function(userInfo){
                me.user = userInfo;
                return this;
            },
            sayHello : function(){
                return alert(me.user.name);
            }
        }
    })();


mysite.init({name : 'Jonathan', age : 17});
mysite.sayHello();
```

I think this will also be good, because mysite will be a single object which can be accessed everywhere.